# Saving split uploaded files from POST end up empty

Tags: java, http, servlets, file-upload, http-post

I am trying to fully implement a resumable file upload system in Java. The library I am using is resumable.js which sends chunks of a file to save as `.part` and then merge them together at the end. When I receive the `POST` request, in my `doPost` method I take the request, save it into a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and then use that to get all the data I need. However, when saving the files as `.part` I end up with them being empty and have a size of 0 bytes.

I have checked and it seems that the data is all there, but I can't seem to get the data to save. Is there something that I implemented incorrectly?

Here is a small snippet of the code I use to do this task:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapReq = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request);
        BufferedReader reader = wrapReq.getReader();
        /**
        * Get some data from the BufferedReader
        */
        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(wrapReq)){
            File mkd = new File(temp_dir);
            if(!mkd.isDirectory())
                mkd.mkdirs();

            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            Iterator<FileItem> iter = upload.parseRequest(request).iterator();
            OutputStream out;

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest_dir));
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                try {

                    FileItem item = iter.next();
                    IOUtils.copy(item.getInputStream(), out);                       
                    logger.debug("Wrote file " + resumableIdentifier + " with chunk number "
                            + resumableChunkNumber + " to " + temp_dir);
                    out.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                    fnfe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        tryCreateFileFromChunks(temp_dir, resumableFileName, resumableChunkSize, resumableTotalSize);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where the `tryCreateFileFromChunks()` method just checks if all the parts are there and merges them. It isn't the problem. The `.part` files themselves are being stored empty.

So, did I handle this the wrong way? I've been struggling to get this working correctly.

Comment: There is at least one error. Your `out.close();` is inside the while loop, whereas you open the stream outside the loop. This must produce wrong results in case you `iter` contains more than one element. I'm not sure if this might solve your problem, but its definitely a bug... Hm, opening a `FileOutputStream` to a directory should fail as well (not sure), open it against the file and not just the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, nor be calling its `getReader()`. The request body can be read only once and you've to choose whether to use `getReader()` method, **or** `getInputStream()` method, **or** `getParameterXxx()` methods on the very same request and not mix them.

Apache Commons FileUpload uses internally `getInputStream()` to parse the request body. But if you've called `getReader()` or `getParameterXxx()` beforehand, then Apache Commons FileUpload will get an empty request body.

All with all, to fix your problem, just get rid of `wrapReq` altogether.

```
if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
    // ...
```

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Comment: But all the information that I need I have to get from the `getReader()` such as the chunk size, file name, chunk number, etc. Is there another way I can get this information? It's not in the header, and calling `getParameterXxx()` doesn't get anything either. The only way I was able to get the data from the request payload was to call `getReader()`

Comment: All this data comes from [Resumable.js's](https://github.com/23/resumable.js) POST requests

Comment: I've never heard of `resumable.js`, but after a quick glance in its documentation it appears that it's actually sending a `multipart/form-data` request with all the mentioned information (chunk size, number, etc) as form data elements. So they are all available in `FileItem` iterator. You just have to check `item.isFormField()` if it's a form field or a file field the usual way. This is in detail elaborated in the "See also" link. Just do as if you're dealing with hidden input fields.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept answer, I had to go to work to apply the changes